# PHP Query not returning results despite it being correct?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that gets data from 2 tables. For some reason the query executes okay and "This renders" appears in my browser, but the foreach loop fails to render anything.

I've tried `$row['customers.first_name'];` but that doesn't help. Is there any glaringly obvious mistakes?

```
$data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM relationships LEFT JOIN customers ON relationships.customer=customers.id WHERE relationships.gym = ? AND relationships.status IS NULL");
$data->execute(array($_SESSION['gymID']));
   
if ($data->execute(array($_SESSION['gymID']))){
   echo 'This renders';
   foreach ($data as $row) {
       echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']. "<br />"; 
       if($row['first_name']){
          $pendingStudents = 1;
       }
 }}
```

Comment: " Is there any glaringly obvious mistakes" is not a proper question to ask, but I linked a post that can give you some pointers in case the query indeed didn't return any rows. but first of all I would check whether foreach loop "renders" at least <br> tags. So you would be able to tell whether it's indeed no results or you just using wrong column names.

Comment: BTW, you are executing your query twice. You need to remove the if condition altogether, as it makes very little sense anyway.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show? If the `echo` in the `foreach()` isn't rendering anything (even the `<br />` tags, which you'd have to inspect in your browser to see), then it's possibly empty (and an empty `array` doesn't do anything in a `foreach()`). Also, is it normal to do `$data->execute()` twice like that? Haven't worked directly with `pdo` in a while.

Comment: @TimLewis FYI, var_dump($data) wouldn't help much, as PDOStatement object doesn't have useful public properties. In order to debug the returned data it's better to check the result of $data->fetchAll() call

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh really eh? That makes my comment a little less helpful than I was hoping for... Good to know for future reference though, and like I said, been a while since I worked with `pdo` directly (too much time working with frameworks).